# Pandas : Assigning values (1,0) to grouped data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` like below :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_3', 'PQRS_4'], 'B':[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df


         |     A      |    B     |
         +------------+----------+
         |    ABCD_1  |    2     |
         |    ABCD_1  |    3     |
         |    ABCD_1  |    5     |
         |    ABCD_1  |    6     |
         |    PQRS_2  |    7     |
         |    PQRS_2  |    8     |
         |    PQRS_2  |    9     |
         |    PQRS_2  |    11    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    13    |
         |    PQRS_3  |    15    |
         |    PQRS_4  |    17    |
         +------------+----------+
```

What I want to achieve is that I need to assign 1 to first value of every group of column `A` and 0 to the rest of other values. Incase, there is a single group present in Column `A` I just assign 1 to that group. So, my expected result should look like below.

```
Expected Output :

         |     A      |    B     |    P     |
         +------------+----------+----------+
         |    ABCD_1  |    2     |     1    |
         |    ABCD_1  |    3     |     0    |
         |    ABCD_1  |    5     |     0    | 
         |    ABCD_1  |    6     |     0    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    7     |     1    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    8     |     0    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    9     |     0    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    11    |     0    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    13    |     0    |
         |    PQRS_3  |    15    |     1    |
         |    PQRS_4  |    17    |     1    |
         +------------+----------+----------+
```

I tried to group them using the below code, however, I wasn't able to get expected results.

```
Actual Output

df['P'] = pd.factorize(df['A']) + 1

         |     A      |    B     |    P     |
         +------------+----------+----------+
         |    ABCD_1  |    2     |     1    |
         |    ABCD_1  |    3     |     1    |
         |    ABCD_1  |    5     |     1    | 
         |    ABCD_1  |    6     |     1    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    7     |     1    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    8     |     2    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    9     |     2    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    11    |     2    |
         |    PQRS_2  |    13    |     2    |
         |    PQRS_3  |    15    |     3    |
         |    PQRS_4  |    17    |     4    |
         +------------+----------+----------+
```

How can I assign 1 and 0 to each of the groups using Pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this as follows:

- Use [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to get a boolean series with `False` for each first group entry and `True` for the others.
- Next, use the unary operator (`~`) to switch `True` and `False` values, and chain [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to turn the booleans into ones (`True`) and zeros (`False`).

```
df['P'] = (~df.A.duplicated()).astype(int)

print(df)

         A   B  P
0   ABCD_1   2  1
1   ABCD_1   3  0
2   ABCD_1   5  0
3   ABCD_1   6  0
4   PQRS_2   7  1
5   PQRS_2   8  0
6   PQRS_2   9  0
7   PQRS_2  11  0
8   PQRS_2  13  0
9   PQRS_3  15  1
10  PQRS_4  17  1
```

Alternatively, but provided that the groups in column `A` are *sorted*, you can also try as follows:

- Compare each row with the next one (see: [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)) with [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html). Each row that is unequal to its shift will give us `True`, all the others will lead to `False`. Afterwards, again chain `astype`.

```
df['P'] = (df.A.ne(df.A.shift())).astype(int)

print(df)

         A   B  P
0   ABCD_1   2  1
1   ABCD_1   3  0
2   ABCD_1   5  0
3   ABCD_1   6  0
4   PQRS_2   7  1
5   PQRS_2   8  0
6   PQRS_2   9  0
7   PQRS_2  11  0
8   PQRS_2  13  0
9   PQRS_3  15  1
10  PQRS_4  17  1
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share research!